# How to remove special characters and space from textbox on keypress/edit

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

The textbox shows phone number with format (###)-###-####. while editing, the space & characters needs to be removed to restrict the count to 10 digits. The onkeypress function is not returning the correct value back.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= TextBox_Phone1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                debugger;               
                var txtphone = $('#<%= TextBox_Phone1.ClientID%>').val();
                $('#<%= TextBox_Phone1.ClientID%>').val = new RegExp(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');

        });
      
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Vani. Please share your JavaScript so others can help.

Comment: Why don't you use HTML input pattern?